# Как сделать Hot Swap Java кода программно?

Tags: java

Вообщем штука такая. Мне нужно подключится к совершенно левому JVM процессу и заменить хотя бы тела ф-ий одного из его классов. На ум сразу же приходит прекрасная ф-ия многих IDE "Hot Swap". Я попытался поискать в гугле документацию по этому поводу, но как не странно топы занимали статьи об использовании Hot Swap, а не о его реализации. Тыкните, пожалуйста, носом туда куда нужно смотреть.

P.S. Подключить JDI я смог, но что то нужных ф-ий я там не нашел.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Debug API, если оно есть.

Comment: Ни одна из известных мне реализаций JVM не поддерживает hot swap. Самое совершенное на сегодняшний день решение - это JRebel. По сути костыль. Это просто агент, отслеживающий временные метки class-файлов, подгружающий более новые и **пытающийся** пересоздать экземпляры этого класса с сохранением их состояния. Даже как средство облегчения процесса разработки JRebel имеет существенные недостатки, в проде использовать его или подобные ему решения нельзя ни в коем случае.